# When calling an operation from the AWS PHP SDK, is there a way to secure its payload contents in a non-readable format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-sdk, aws-secrets-manager, aws-php-sdk

I've recently used the PHP SDK to test some operations under the SecretsManager service. Everything works fine. However, I needed to ensure the information sent in using the **`createSecret`** operation was safe from any third-party threats.

So I did a small investigation to view the request's body contents. I was able to view this content under ***StreamRequestPayloadMiddleware.php***.

After modifying it by using **json_decode** to view the request's contents, I came across this:

```
array(4) { 
    ["Name"]=> string(9) "demo/Test" 
    ["SecretString"]=> string(39) "{"username":"Tom","password":"Test123"}" 
    ["KmsKeyId"]=> string(xx) "arn:aws:kms:xx-xxxx-x:xxxxxxxxxx:key/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxx" 
    ["ClientRequestToken"]=> string(xx) "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" 
}
```

I then realized the plaintext contents of the **SecretString** were visible in the request's body.

I'm aware the SecretsManager uses a KMS key to encrypt the secret values; however, this only happens once the operation has been sent to the server-side (AWS Console).

Therefore, I need to know if there is any way to protect the payload contents in an **encrypted format** so that the SecretsManager service or AWS can **unpack this content to its original value** without having it saved in that encrypted format, on a new secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traffic between user and service endpoint is encrypted by default through a secure HTTPS/TLS connection.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/data-protection.html

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, yes I was aware of this, however, what I was proposing is an extra measure when posting such sensitive information. AWS itself introduced an Encryption SDK however there is no support for PHP yet and it sends the contents in its encrypted format. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/introduction.html

Comment: In my opinion TLS 1.2 is enough secure to transfer secrets unless you have a high secure user case. If you do, I would not recommend using cloud services at all. Because it is not possible to use special encryption methods with AWS Secrets Manager, one solution could be creating a Lambda function to retrieve the encrypted payload, decrypt it and store the secret in the Secrets Manager. This would be a little bit safer because decrypting and storing procedures happen inside AWS infrastructure.

Comment: Using Lamda is also a possible solution, but it might not be cost-effective I think. I was hoping AWS might have had a solution to cater to this matter. But again thanks for the insight, Marko!